# Accessing dependencies for react-toggle-component

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to use this react library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toggle-component) and having a bit of a hard time getting it to work.

I've installed the dependencies required through npm (react, react-circle, react-dom, and styled-components).
After installing these dependencies and trying to install react-toggle-component, I get the error 'Could not find a declaration file for module 'react'. Try `npm install @types/react` (Same error for styled-components). So I followed this command and the react-toggle-component installed successfully.

Now when I try to use the component in my react component, I am using it just like in the suggested use:

```
import React from "react"

import Toggle from "react-toggle-component"

function Application() {

  return <Toggle name="toggle-1" />;

}
```

But when I run my app, I get the following error:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

I don't completely understand why I had to install the react and styled-components' types definitions, and I'm wondering if that is causing my application not to find the Toggle component.

If you could point me in the right direction, or give me any sort of help understanding this I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the documentation was wrong. The component appears to have been exported as a named export, thus I had to import with the following command:

```
import {Toggle} from "react-toggle-component"
```

As per the explanation here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12214